# How to flip a Three.js texture horizontally

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making a 360 viewer, so textures are inside a cylinder. Problem is that they appear inverted horizontally.

I know about `texture.flipY` but I haven't found a `texture.flipX` on [the source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/textures/Texture.js).

So how can I flip a texture horizontally, or along the x axis, directly in the code? (not using an image editor)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer was easier than I thought.

```
cylinder.scale.x = -1;
```

And don't forget to add

```
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

Comment: well your question was pertaining to textures not objects.

Comment: for pure textures (i.e images) use a library like [filter.js](https://github.com/foo123/FILTER.js) (ps i'm author)

Comment: Given there is no texture.flipX, this seem the only practical approach.
I found I also need rotate the object that the texture is mapped to:
object.rotation.y = Math.PI;

Comment: I think a more practical approach is to go through the geometry UV coordinates and flip them.

Comment: Adding to @WestLangley's comment above, my understanding is that THREE.js does now support negative scale, as of end-2017.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/12787

Comment: @DiarmidMackenzie Thanks. I removed my comment to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 25):

To flip a texture horizontally, you can do the following:

```js
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.x = - 1;
```

three.js r.147

Comment: I did this, but instead of flipping the texture I got 1px of the texture expanded across the whole object.

Comment: I tried this with a dynamic texture from a camera and rendered to an in-scene plane  and it worked nicely. plane1.material.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
 plane1.material.map.repeat.x = -1;

Comment: This works, but it also requires power-of-two texture sizes.

Comment: Same issue as @Pier, 1px of the image gets stretched across the face. The image is 512 x 1024.

Comment: for a texture with size not power of two, `RepeatWrapping` will fail on iOS safari

Answer (score 2):

It might seem a bit of an overkill, but I think a nice way to do it is to turn it by 180 degrees (PI radians) around it's center then flip it:

```js
texture.center = new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0.5);
texture.rotation = Math.PI;
texture.flipY = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach here is to change the geometry. In the cylinder geometry you specify `thetaStart` and `thetaLength` for the cylinder section you want to render, and usually you choose a positive angle, i.e. `thetaLength>0`. If instead you pass `thetaStart + thetaLength` and `-thetaLength` to `CylinderBufferGeometry`, the cylinder is rendered clockwise instead of counter-clockwise, and all face normals now point inwards. So, there is no need to flip the texture anymore.