# Three.JS UV Mapping for partial spheres

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900677/mapping-a-stereographic-projection-to-the-inside-of-a-sphere-in-threejs/) I was looking to map a stereographic projection onto a sphere for the sake of live-streaming a virtual reality event.

I ultimately learned quite a bit about UV mapping and was able to construct a very accurate mapping that looks incredible. However there's one thing I don't like about this mapping method: there's a hack where the bottom of the sphere has to map to "nothing", so I map it to a corner of the texture.

In an effort to improve upon this solution, I tried creating only a partial sphere by adjusting the theta length per the [Three.JS documentation on SphereGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/SphereGeometry).

While I got the shape of the sphere right, I noticed something odd about the UV mapping:

```
var fov = 270;
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(
    1, // Radius
    50, // Horizontal segments
    50, // Vertical segments
    0, // Phi start
    2 * Math.PI, // Phi length
    Math.acos((360 - fov) * Math.PI / 180 / 2), // Theta start
    Math.PI - Math.acos((360 - fov) * Math.PI / 180 / 2) // Theta length
);
var minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ;
var faceVertexUvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];
for ( var i = 0; i < faceVertexUvs.length; i++ ) {
    var face = geometry.faces[i];
    for ( var j = 0; j < 3; j ++ ) {
        var x = face.vertexNormals[j].x;
        var y = face.vertexNormals[j].y;
        var z = face.vertexNormals[j].z;

        // Capture the upper and lower bounds for all points
        if (!minX || x < minX) minX = x;
        if (!maxX || x > maxX) maxX = x;
        if (!minY || y < minY) minY = y;
        if (!maxY || y > maxX) maxY = y;
        if (!minZ || z < minZ) minZ = z;
        if (!maxZ || z > maxZ) maxZ = z;
    }
}
console.log("minX: " + minX + ", maxX: " + maxX);
console.log("minY: " + minY + ", maxY: " + maxY);
console.log("minZ: " + minZ + ", maxZ: " + maxZ);
```

I learned previously when performing UV mapping that the `x`, `y`, and `z` values range from `-1` to `1` - regardless of the actual size of the mesh. If the sphere had a radius of 1 or a radius of 100, an `x` value of 1 means "the far right of the sphere" and a `y` value of 1 means "the top of the sphere". However when I have an incomplete sphere like this (using `thetaStart` and `thetaLength` to cut a hole in the top of the sphere) suddenly `maxY` was equal to about 0.7854.

Why is it that this mesh ends at 0.7854 instead of scaling from -1 to 1? I had hoped that by changing the shape of the sphere I could simplify my UV mapping logic (removing the `scaledY` term from my previous question that I linked) however altering the shape of the sphere seems to have had **no** affect on the UV map.

Is there a way to tell Three.JS that this partial sphere is the full shape and its coordinates should range from -1 to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're confusing Normals with UVs in your description and code snippet. You're reading the value of Normals above in these lines:

```
    var x = face.vertexNormals[j].x;
    var y = face.vertexNormals[j].y;
    var z = face.vertexNormals[j].z;
```

With your SphereGeometry attributes, the min and max y **normals** match the expected result: [image]

What you want to do is look at the min and max **UV** values. I've updated the code to get UV values:

```
var fov = 270;
var geometry:THREE.SphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(
    2, // Radius
    50, // Horizontal segments
    50, // Vertical segments
    0, // Phi start
    2 * Math.PI, // Phi length
    Math.acos((360 - fov) * Math.PI / 180 / 2), // Theta start
    Math.PI - Math.acos((360 - fov) * Math.PI / 180 / 2) // Theta length
);
var minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ;
var faceVertexUvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];

for ( var i = 0; i < faceVertexUvs.length; i++ ) {
    var vertUV = faceVertexUvs[i];
    for ( var j = 0; j < 3; j ++ ) {
        var x = vertUV[j].x;
        var y = vertUV[j].y;

        // Capture the upper and lower bounds for all points
        if (!minX || x < minX) minX = x;
        if (!maxX || x > maxX) maxX = x;
        if (!minY || y < minY) minY = y;
        if (!maxY || y > maxX) maxY = y;
    }
}
console.log("minX: " + minX + ", maxX: " + maxX);
console.log("minY: " + minY + ", maxY: " + maxY);
```

When you run this code, you'll see that the range is always `[0, 1]`, not `[-1, 1]`. Additionally, keep in mind that UVs don't have a Z value; only X and Y, since they're used to map a 2-dimensional image.

**Normals:**

- x: (-1, 1)
- y: (-1, 1)
- z: (-1, 1)

**UVs:**

- x: [0, 1]
- y: [0, 1]

You can see how ThreeJS builds sphere UVs in [this code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/geometries/SphereGeometry.js), specifically in lines 90, 94, and 111.

Comment: It's likely I'm very confused because I'm fairly new to the concept of UV mapping. I was aware that the normals referred to points on the polygon in 3D space, and the UVs referred to points on the texture in 2D space. I also knew the UVs ranged from `[0, 1]`. However I thought the normals **always** ranged from `[-1, 1]`. When I make a sphere of radius 100, the normals still range from `[-1, 1]` - suggesting it's not tied to the physical size of the mesh. So I thought `1` meant "the top of the mesh", regardless of shape or size.

Comment: When creating a sphere, the normals are [perpendicular to the face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) in X,Y,Z space. But since your sphere doesn't have a "north pole", you won't encounter a normal pointing straight up. That's why you were finding that your maximum y-value was 0.7854.

Comment: That makes sense, but raises some new questions about how someone is supposed to create a UV map for meshes with two faces pointed in the same direction (like a donut, where both the inner and outer rings have faces pointing in all cardinal directions). Thanks for explaining.

Comment: [This example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometries) is good at illustrating how ThreeJS defines its UVs by mapping [this image](https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg) over its standard geometries, including a donut (A.K.A. torus). Now, to map your own textures, that depends on the software you're using.