# How can I flip a Three.js VideoTexture horizontally?

Tags: video, three.js, flip, videotexture

We are using the front camera feed as a VideoTexture for the background of the Three.js Scene. This video is flipped compared to the way the front-facing camera normally works. Is there a way to flip the video / VideoTexture so that it will work as we expect?

I have tried the method shown in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974578/how-to-flip-a-three-js-texture-horizontally). This doesn't work, I think, because the video feed isn't a power of 2.

I have looked through the Three.js docs for [VideoTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/VideoTexture) and [Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture) but there only seems to be a way to flip vertically. This is also mentioned in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974578/how-to-flip-a-three-js-texture-horizontally), because "There is no WebGL flag for `gl.UNPACK_FLIP_X_WEBGL`..."

Is there anyway to flip the video horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on to what @pailhead suggested and talking with a coworker, I came up with a solution. The only thing that is by guess is the '14' as shown below.

```
function scaleBG(workCam, scaleObj) {
  var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  var alpha = ((workCam.fov / 2.0) * Math.PI / 180);
  var beta = (90.0 * Math.PI / 180.0); 
  var gamma = ((180.0 - alpha - beta) * Math.PI / 180.0);

  var c = workCam.far - camZOffset - 1.0;
  var a = c * Math.sin(alpha) / Math.sin(gamma);
  var b = c * Math.sin(beta) / Math.sin(gamma);
  var width = a * 2 / (window.innerWidth / 14);

  scaleObj.scale.set(-width, width / aspectRatio, 1);
  scaleObj.position.set(camXOffset,0,-c);
}
```

The scale change by '14' feels good but I am not sure if there is a better way to calculate that value. However, for now this works for me quite well.

**Edit 1**

Looks like the width value works for mobile but is small on desktop. May need to do some math based on the ppi?

Answer (score 0):

You can render a quad  behind the scene and rotate it or scale it negatively (instead of using `.background`).

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but it brings up a whole host of other issues.

How can I make it scaled to be the size of the screen? How can I make sure it is behind the objects being rendered? Etc. 

I am going to keep thinking about this but if I can find a way to just flip the VideoTexture itself, that would be ideal.

Comment: I added to your suggestion and have posted the code that made it work for me.